# "conda activate" is not redirecting python?

Tags: python, conda

I have a `conda` env named `py36` with python3.6 in it:  (yea I know it is deprecated - there's a surprising amount of legacy code on older/unsupported versions..)

```
(py36) 11:34:52/py36 $conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3
..
py36                  *  /Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/envs/py36
```

Let's double-check the python version:

```
(py36) 11:35:12/py36 $/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/envs/py36/bin/python -V
Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Let's activate it:

```
$conda activate py36
(py36) $python -V
Python 3.9.12
```

So then why was the version unchanged?   I searched for answers and discovered there is an open bug with `conda`  [PATH not set by conda activate](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392) .  The main workaround - to include a package when creating the env - did not work. This is specifically what I tried

```
conda create -n py366 PYTHON=3.6 pip
$conda activate py366
$ (py366) $python -V
Python 3.9.12
```

Can anyone chime in on a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is an update to my `$PATH` in the `.bash_profile` *below* the section for `conda_init()` .  Moving the `$PATH` modification before the `conda_init()` within the `.bash_profile` resolved this issue.